# Error running NUnit tests on Build Agent

Tags: nunit-3.0

My environment is TFS 2013 and VS 2013 using NUnit 3.2.1. I am getting the error:
"Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests".

I think it is because I have NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0 and need 3.2.1.
Where do I find this? It is not in https://dist.nuget.org/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to install NUnit 3.2.1. To install NUnit, run the following command in the [Package Manager Console](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console):

```
Install-Package NUnit
```

Check: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/3.2.1

Comment: Unfortunately I have been to that site several times and only version 2.9 is available for VS 2013. Is 3.2.1 for use with VS 2013?

Comment: I managed to get farther along by using Package manger to install the NUnit3 Test Adapter with the command Install-Package Nunit3TestAdaptor

Comment: I changed NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0 to 3.2.1and now the tests run, but I still get the error:  "Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests".

Comment: I think this may be because I have both NUnitTestAdapter both 2.0.0 and 3.2.1 installed. I say this because I see this when I run the tests locally. NUnit Adapter 3.0.10.0: Test execution complete. So those tests are OK.
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started. Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests in.... so that is where the error is and I really don't want to run 2.0.0. How to uninstall 2.0.0?

Comment: In VS, go to Tools--Extensions and Updates, find NUnit Test Adapter 2.0.0.0 in Installed tab, and click Uninstall.

Comment: Thanks @Cece, I have accepted your answer as that gets me to where I have the tests working properly when run locally. However, I still have that error on the build agent machine. I did check and NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0 is not installed on that machine... so the error has some other cause on that machine.

Comment: Got rid of all exceptions by cleaning folders of residual files on build agent. Thanks for the help!